# Disable scrolling by touch in pagepiling

Tags: javascript, pagepiling.js

I use the [pagepiling.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/) library, how can I disable navigation by touch in the mobile?
In the mobile, the slide can be changed with a finger on the screen. How to disable?

Comment: I would encourage you to make use of the fullPage.js library instead, is big brother. 
You can then use the [Parallax extension](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/parallax.html) to emulate the pagePiling.js behaviour as detailed [here on this post](https://alvarotrigo.com/blog/how-create-tumblr-website-effect/). 
Then you'll be able to enjoy from all fullpage.js features ,including responsive options and turnf Off the piling effect.

Comment: tnx @Alvaro .worked, method setAllowScrolling(false), [link method's](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/methods.html#secondPage/3).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: `setAllowScrolling(boolean, [directions])`

```
$.fn.pagepiling.setAllowScrolling(false);
```

For disabling keyboard scrolling:

```
$.fn.pagepiling.setKeyboardScrolling(false);
```

For disabling mouse wheel scrolling:

```
$.fn.pagepiling.setMouseWheelScrolling(false);
```